# error of dereferencing pointer, in struct

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

I tried all the solutions on the site and didn't manage to fix this problem
i got a declared struct in my header

```
struct _fileNew;
typedef struct _fileNew fileNew;
```

in my source file I defined fileNew

```
struct _fileNew
{
     char chars[];
};
```

now in my main i tried printing something inside the struct

```
fileNew*  blu;
int i;
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    blu->chars[i] = 'b';
}
printf("%s", blu->chars);
```

and i got

error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
I ran a debug and i saw that the cahrs was filled correctly but it won't print it. and I doin something wrong in the source file while defining the fileNew.?

thanks!

Comment: There are many errors in your code. First, you have to make the `struct` *definition* available to `main`. You can fix that by putting it in the header file. Then, you need to initialize pointers before you de-reference them.

Comment: I have an include in the main, for the header. what do u mean by initialize pointers before you de-reference them

Comment: Put the struct *definition* in the header, not the "source file".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate a memory block for the structure in heap and assign its  address to Your pointer.
In C every string ends with a '\0' (string terminator), so You need to add it also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 128

struct _fileNew;
typedef struct _fileNew fileNew;

struct _fileNew
{
    char chars[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
};

int main()
{
    fileNew *blu = malloc(sizeof *blu);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        blu->chars[i] = 'b';
    }
    blu->chars[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s", blu->chars);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You only have a pointer that is not actually pointing to anything and need to allocate size for the char[].  In main you need to assign the pointer to point at the declared struct OR use malloc as the other answers suggest:

```
static fileNew blu;
fileNew *p_blu = &blu;
...
p_blu->chars[i] = 'b';
```

Comment: it's not the fix.. changed nothing

Comment: This is correct, but the "incomplete type" error means the definition of the struct isn't available.

Comment: Also, `&_fileNew` isn't a thing.